# Show what's current value of registers. (AArch64 Android assembly debugging)

Tags: android, debugging, assembly, cpu-registers, arm64

I want see what's happening inside of all registers from my program.

I have this code that works fine on AArch64 Linux as a static executable.

```
.data

msg:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"
len = . - msg

.text

.globl _start
_start:
 mov x0, #0x1
 ldr x1, =msg
 ldr x2, =len
 mov x8, #0x40
 svc #0x0

 mov x0, #0x0
 mov x8, #0x5d
 svc #0x0
```

And compile and run it with this command (in Termux on Android).

```
as hello.s -o hello.o
ld hello.o -o hello
./hello
```

Unlike in emulation of 8086 processor application (emu8086), I can see step by step how CPU fetching, decoding, and executing inside of that emulator also what is current register value also current memory value and its addresses.

In this real assembly (not emulation), I even can't see what is memory value in addresses.

I was thinking about to use `gdb`. But I think I need example how to use it.

At least I want see:

- Current value of all registers.
- Current value of program address in memory.
- Flag register

Comment: GDB's TUI mode does this: `layout reg` (and `layout next` or `layout prev` to toggle regs+source vs. regs+disassembly).  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for GDB asm tips; much of it should apply equally to AArch64.  Or use a GUI front-end for GDB, like https://www.gdbgui.com/ (which uses a browser tab for its GUI, but does run locally.)

Comment: Use a debugger.  There are some visual debuggers that should fit your bill.  Unfortunately I don't know their names.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have installed from ```pipx```, unfortunately it's failed to run the gdbgui server. Maybe it's not match for android environtment. I was running it from termux.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to run stuff in an Android/Linux system, not an AArch64 GNU/Linux system like a Raspberry Pi?  I'm not surprised GDBgui couldn't start a browser tab on an Android system, with its very different security model from a GNU/Linux desktop!

Comment: @PeterCordes yes

Answer (score 0):

So far I was tinkering `gdb`

And here what I learned

Suppose the program still same like my post.

To start debug just simply

`gdb ./hello`

Then it will show up gdb interpreter

- To add breakpoint

```
b _start
```

It will add breakpoint 1
Then add again if necessary

```
b *_start+4
```

It will add breakpoint 2
And so on until end of program.

Run the program by just simply

```
run
```

It will run breakpoint 1

Okay now to show current memory value just simply

```
x /5i _start
```

It will show first 5 memory value in instruction format from _start.

```
0x4000b0 <_start>:
    mov x0, #0x1                        // #1
=> 0x4000b4 <_start+4>: ldr     x1, 0x4000d0 <_start+32>
   0x4000b8 <_start+8>: ldr     x2, 0x4000d8 <_start+40>
   0x4000bc <_start+12>:
    mov x8, #0x40                       // #64
   0x4000c0 <_start+16>:        svc     #0x0
```

`=>` marks mean current breakpoint

To show current register just type

```
i r
```

Then type `n` to exexute next breakpoint.

Okay so far it's burdening enough usig gdb, I wish there's easiest way to add breakpoint from specific address to end address with step +4.

Also I still didnt figure out how to see flag register.

I'm still expecting if `gdb` show current register value, current memory value, and current flag register value in one display/screen. and when I next breakpoint the screen will autoupdate ,Also I expecting it's adding breakpoint from _start, _start+4, and so on.. without add manually one by one like above

Comment: If you want to step one instruction at a time, use `si` which effectively executes one instruction and then breaks. You don't need to manually set a new breakpoint every time.  Or `ni` which steps over a subroutine call instead of into it, like setting a breakpoint on the instruction following the `bl`.  Also useful is `display/i $pc` which disassembles the next instruction to be executed.

Comment: The flags are shown in the `info registers` (aka `i r`) output, in the `cpsr` row: the letters `N C Z V` will be shown if the corresponding flags are set.  You can also get this line by itself with `p $cpsr`.

Comment: If GDB's TUI mode (`layout reg`) doesn't work, you can still `display /x $x1` or whatever on a few different registers, to set up some things to be printed before every prompt.  It's a bit clunky, but you can choose the format and even use an expression like `display (char*)($x3)` to show the pointed-to string, or `display *(int*)$x2` to (try to) deref something.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes it wasn't working until I compile with generating debug information with this command ```as hello.s -o hello.o -g``` so basically I just need add ```-g``` flags according ```as --help``` that flag will generating debug information.

Comment: `layout reg` seem to defaults to regs + source these days, so use `layout next` after that to go to regs + disassembly which used to be how `layout reg` worked.  You don't need debug info to debug asm, unless you want to see your comments.  It can actually be helpful to see disassembly, in case something didn't assemble the way you expected and the disassembler printing it in canonical form clues you in to something you missed.

Comment: Okay thankyou, it was about register. Now I want see memory layout, so i can see byte value of memory addresses. I expect memory addresses shown in relative address format (which from label like _start+8) and absolute addresses. Also I want see value of memory in ascii format and in hexadecimal format. Moreless like emu8086 layout.

Comment: Okay theres no layout memory but instead layout asm, I was using ```layout asm```. And the value of memory shown it as instruction instead of ascii or hexadecimal value. I want see ```Hello world\n``` stored in memory addresses. I wish there's layout that shown it. Instead debugger shown that data as instruction.

Comment: Nevermind, I can just use ```x/c <address where hello world first char>```